How to define custom property in angular class
I developed a mat-table in a angular 17 project, but when application is running "productName" custom property is not working in the table.
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label> </mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="type here to search" #input>
  </mat-form-field>
  
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="productName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.productName}}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
      </ng-container>
   
      <!-- Quantity Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Quantity </th> 
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Value" [value]="row.quantity" [(ngModel)]="row.quantity">
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>        
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- UnitPrice Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="unitPrice">
        <th class="right-aligned" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Unit Price </th>
        <td class="right-aligned" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.unitPrice | currency}} </td>
        <td class="right-aligned" mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>Total</td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- lineTotal Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="lineTotal">
        <th class="right-aligned" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total </th>
        <td class="right-aligned" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{(row.quantity*row.unitPrice) | currency}} </td>
        <td class="right-aligned" mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{getTotal() | currency}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns;"></tr>

      <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
      <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of items"></mat-paginator>
  </div>

defined classes are given below,
export class ShoppingCartItem {
      shoppingCartID: number=0;     
      productID: number=0;
      unitPrice: number=0;
      lineDiscount: number=0;
      quantity: number=0;
      id: number=0;
      createdDate: Date=new Date;
      modifiedDate: Date=new Date;
      isDeleted: boolean=false;
      rowVersion: string="";
      productName?:string | undefined;
      shoppingCart?: ShoppingCart | undefined;
      product?: Product | undefined;           
      constructor(){
        if(this.product != null){
          this.productName=this.product.name; 
        }
        else{ this.productName=""; 
        }
      }           
    } 

export class Product{
    id: number=0;
    name: string=""; 
    inventories: Inventory[]=[];    
    productCategoryID: number=0;      
    reOrderLevel: number=0;
    taxGroupID?: number | undefined;
    taxInclude: boolean=false;
    taxRate: number=0;
    productImage: string="";
    taxGroup?: TaxGroup | undefined;   
    productCategory?: ProductCategory | undefined;    
    createdDate: Date=new Date;
    modifiedDate: Date=new Date;
    isDeleted: boolean=false;
    rowVersion: string="";     
}

can anyone give idea how to assign values to "productName" property in above "ShoppingCartItem" class?. currently "productName" property is assigned values in the constructor, but it is not working.

You can either have a getter method to get the product name, this property is read only since you have only a getter.
export class ShoppingCartItem {
      shoppingCartID: number=0;     
      productID: number=0;
      unitPrice: number=0;
      lineDiscount: number=0;
      quantity: number=0;
      id: number=0;
      createdDate: Date=new Date;
      modifiedDate: Date=new Date;
      isDeleted: boolean=false;
      rowVersion: string="";
      productName?:string | undefined;
      shoppingCart?: ShoppingCart | undefined;
      product?: Product | undefined;           
      constructor(){ }     
     
      get productName() {
         return this.product?.name;
      }      
    } 

We can use the type safe access of typescript ?. to access the name prop
Else just directly access the name in the html using the same typesafe access
  <ng-container matColumnDef="productName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.product?.name}}</td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
  </ng-container>

If none of the methods work. Then first check why product is not set properly in your code.
